# WPF livechart not renderring correctly

Tags: c#, wpf, livecharts

I'am using [livecharts](https://lvcharts.net/) to display 3 Solid Gauges.
The "Value" and "To" Values are a simple Bindings.
My third chart displays the correctly Value as Label, but the ActiveFill wont show up correctly.

[image: screenshot of the actual result]

My xaml:

```
<lvc:Gauge
        Width="100"
        Height="100"
        Margin="0,10,270,0"
        HorizontalAlignment="Right"
        VerticalAlignment="Top"
        FontFamily="Roboto Black"
        Foreground="#fff"
        GaugeActiveFill="#c82333"
        GaugeBackground="#FF202225"
        Value="{Binding DescError}"
        From="0"
        To="{Binding DescCount}" />
    <lvc:Gauge
        Width="100"
        Height="100"
        Margin="0,10,150,0"
        HorizontalAlignment="Right"
        VerticalAlignment="Top"
        FontFamily="Roboto Black"
        Foreground="#fff"
        GaugeActiveFill="#e0a800"
        GaugeBackground="#FF202225"
        Value="{Binding DescWarning}"
        From="0"
        To="{Binding DescCount}" />
    <lvc:Gauge
        Width="100"
        Height="100"
        Margin="0,10,40,0"
        HorizontalAlignment="Right"
        VerticalAlignment="Top"
        FontFamily="Roboto Black"
        Foreground="#fff"
        GaugeActiveFill="#28a745"
        GaugeBackground="#FF202225"
        Value="{Binding DescOk}"
        From="0"
        To="{Binding DescCount}" />
```

I have no idea why this happens.
The bindings are all ok, right values are there. 
Anyone out there with an idea?

Answer (score 3):

I had the same Issue and what I found out was that, at least for me, it is always the Gauge at the very bottom of the code which does not function properly. So a little workaround from my side was to just add another Gauge which has no functionality and is invisible by setting the `GaugeActiveFill` and the `Foreground` Property to the Color of the Background. Also set `Height="0"` and `Width="0"`

e.g.:

```
<lvc:Gauge Height="0" Width="0"
               Uses360Mode="True"
               From="0" To="1" Value="1" Foreground="White" GaugeActiveFill="White"/>
```

might not be a very professional Solution but I found no other way to fix this issue

Answer (score -1):

Test with Padding. Change the Padding from the "4".
This will be remove the pixels.